# how can i pass images recaptcha from any site?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, captcha

hello and thanks in advance!
                           I want to bypass recaptcha in this site: [https://www.spectrum.com/login].
i am using antiCaptha and I also have api_key but don't have access to site_key. i think I only need site_key to bypass this. or you have any other method to bypass this. please help me. here is my code:

```
from function import antiCaptcha
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='C:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.spectrum.net/login')



result = antiCaptcha(key)
```

anticaptcha file:

```
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask


def antiCaptcha(key):
    api_key = '840877d7bfba4eb2b574c4a6b86a4468'
    site_key = '6LfIq-QUAAAAAMXtvWG1S1WY-WItR26ICRT6eOXZ'  # grab from site
    url = 'https://www.spectrum.net/login'
    client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
    task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(url, key)
    job = client.createTask(task)
    job.join()
    print(job.get_solution_response())
    return job.get_solution_response()
```

it is also showing an error in importing python_anticaptcha:

```
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7f7fb8547ba7> in <module>
----> 1 from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_anticaptcha'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sitekey of the site you need to bypass captcha on is "6LfRsggUAAAAABJBT04IBvG0gWCNSB_FuhkC4PAx". You can see it in the page code here (it's "k" parameter):
[image: how to get sitekey]

Regarding anticaptcha I can't help you though, since personally I use 2captcha because it's cheaper and works way faster. In case you want to try them, you may want to check these links:

1) https://github.com/2captcha/2captcha-api-examples/blob/master/ReCaptcha%20v2%20API%20Examples/Python%20Example/2captcha_python_api_example.py

2) https://github.com/MackOsmium/Better-2Captcha

3) https://github.com/athre0z/twocaptcha-api

as well as official API description:
https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_recaptchav2_new

Comment: I grabbed this in my code and also generated token from site_key and also successful in adding the token to text area field but I have stuck on the last step which is to execute a javascript function for submitting it. like google uses "onSuccess" on his Recaptcha demo form. now I just want that javascript function name to complete my work.

Comment: You should find and execute the callback function.
Here is the easy way: https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#callback
Or the hard way: https://captchaforum.com/threads/problem-with-invisible-recaptcha-v2-callback-function-at-mail-com-sign-up-page.56/